# WIndows Service Could Not Find File

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have `windows service` which works on my machine without problem. When I installed it on another machine it `throws` exception `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`. The service is run as Local System.
The problem is that is does not go inside the body of the thread method. There is no sense to me to throw such kind of exception.

The line of which this happens is.

```
    Thread action = new Thread( () => {
     try 
      {
         using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(..., false))
         {
         ...
         }
         })
      }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {...}
```

What could be the problem for this exception ?

Comment: What´s happening within the Thread?

Comment: I'd try to log the name of the file being opened. That is, to be sure `Settings.Default.ProcFilePath/Name` returns what you think.

Comment: Does the file exist? Did you set all of the `Settings.Default.X` values.  If you set a breakpoint, or log the filename, do you get the filename you expect? (Edit: @Micke beat me to the second point.)

Comment: Yes if i set breakpoing there is a file. I also have try { ... } catch { ... } block to catch if file is not found. But this stops the entire service with File Not Found exception.

Comment: It you are setting a breakpoint, you are probably in the debugger, not running as LocalSystem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that assembly `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` was missing on the disk.